# Is there any service at IntelliJ IDEA website/api which can be used to gather analytic data?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I've created plugin for intellij-idea and android studio.
Is there a possibility to gather some anonymous usage statistics of that plugin from users? For example how many users are using that plugin via idea or android studio.

Comment: A lot of IntelliJ users, like me, are behind a firewall, because our companies strongly object to this sort of thing. However, you can always write your own service, host it in the cloud, and connect to it in your plugin.

Comment: Currently there is no existing API you could (re-)use to collect 3rd party plugins usage data.

Comment: I agree there is no API that can be used here. But I have found a open project - https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/. It uses google analytics to gather data about any user action we want. Thanks for help and I hope it's going to be useful for someone else.